# javascript click event separation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to separate the click event.

All the clicks inside the `body` tag have to be alerted "outside table",

except the click event inside `postit-table` class.

This is my code:

**html**

```
<table class="postit-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="postit-header">
        <td>header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea class="postit-content"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**css**

```
.postit-table{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**javascript(jquery):**

```
$("body").bind('click',':not(".postit-table,.postit-table tbody, .postit-table tr, .postit-table tbody tr td")', function (e) {
    alert("clicked outside table!");
});

$(".postit-table").click(function(){
    alert("clicked inside table!");
});
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/c5fomgp1/

Unfortunately, if you run the fiddle app, it still calls the outside table click event :(

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation()` on `postit-table` click event: 
doing so the click event won't be propagated bubbling up to the `body` element

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/e5jph1Lt/

```
$("body").on('click', function() {
    alert("clicked outside table!");
});

$(".postit-table").on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert("clicked inside table!");
});
```

As a sidenote, use `on()` instead of `bind()` if you use a recent jQuery version

Answer (score 3):

Solved

```
$("body").bind('click',':not(".postit-table,.postit-table tbody, .postit-table tr, .postit-table tbody tr td")', function (e) {
    alert("clicked outside table!");
});

$(".postit-table").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("clicked inside table!");
});
```

Also Try fro this have other solution .
Chears

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Code

http://jsfiddle.net/9e5128g1/

Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Ref.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Looks overcomplicated to me. As already answered by others you can use `event.stopPropagation` an simplify your code. Something like:

```
$(document).on('click', clickedoutside);
$('body').on('click', '.postit-table', clicked);

function clicked(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('clicked inside table!');
};

function clickedoutside(e){
    alert('clicked <b>outside</b> table!');
};
```

Here's your rewritten [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/38baokda/)